# Transliterate the dynamic NextJS route and put hyphens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, lodash

I have a website on next.js with mdx. There I have articles that have tags, they are specified in the frontmatter like this `tags: ['functions', 'javascript', 'powerful code', 'js']`. I also have routing by tags - along the path `pages/blog/tag/[tag].js` pages are created where all articles with the corresponding tags are collected.

This is what my service function looks like, which creates everything necessary to generate articles on the right routes:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import matter from 'gray-matter';

export function getAllPosts() {
    const files = fs.readdirSync('./content/posts');
    const posts = files
      .map((fileName) => {
        const slug = fileName.replace(/\.mdx$/, '');
        const { frontmatter } = getPostBySlug(slug);
        return {
          slug,
          ...frontmatter,
        };
      })

    return posts;
  }

export function getPostBySlug(slug) {
    const fileName = fs.readFileSync(`content/posts/${slug}.mdx`, 'utf-8');
    const { data: frontmatter, content } = matter(fileName);
    return {
      frontmatter,
      content,
    };
  }


export function getAllWork() {
    const data = fs.readFileSync('content/work/data.json', 'utf-8');
    const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    return jsonData.work;
}

export function getAllPostsByTag({ tag }) {
    const posts = getAllPosts();
    return posts.filter((post) => post.tags.includes(tag));
}
```

This is how the file looks like `pages/blog/tag/[tag].js`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import {getAllPosts, getAllPostsByTag} from "@/lib/getAllData";
import Head from "next/head";
import Article from "@/components/article";


export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const posts = getAllPosts();
    const tags = new Set(posts.flatMap((post) => post.tags));

    return {
        paths: [...tags].map((tag) => {
            return {
                params: {
                    tag
                }
            }
        }),
        fallback: false,
    };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params: { tag } }) {
    const posts = getAllPostsByTag({tag});

    return {
        props: {
            posts,
            tag
        },
    };
}

export default function Tag({ posts, tag }) {

    const numberPosts = 2

    // State for the list
    const [list, setList] = useState([...posts.slice(0, numberPosts)])

    // State to trigger oad more
    const [loadMore, setLoadMore] = useState(false)

    // State of whether there is more to load
    const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(posts.length > numberPosts)

    // Load more button click
    const handleLoadMore = () => {
        setLoadMore(true)
    }

    // Handle loading more articles
    useEffect(() => {
        if (loadMore && hasMore) {
        const currentLength = list.length
        const isMore = currentLength < posts.length
        const nextResults = isMore
            ? posts.slice(currentLength, currentLength + numberPosts)
            : []
        setList([...list, ...nextResults])
        setLoadMore(false)
        }
    }, [loadMore, hasMore]) //eslint-disable-line

    //Check if there is more
    useEffect(() => {
        const isMore = list.length < posts.length
        setHasMore(isMore)
    }, [list]) //eslint-disable-line


    return (
        <div>
            <Head>
                <title>NextJS Blog</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/public/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <section className='px-6'>
                <div className='max-w-4xl mx-auto'>
                    <h1 className='text-3xl font-bold mb-6 p-4'>All `{tag}` posts</h1>
                    {list.map((post) => (
                        <Article key={post.slug} className='border-b-2' post={post} />
                    ))}
                </div>
                {hasMore ? (
                <div><button onClick={handleLoadMore}>Еще статьи</button></div>
                ) : (
                    <div><button disabled>Больше нет статей</button></div>
                )}
            </section>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The fact is that routes are created normally when my tag in the frontmatter of my .md file is written in English (Latin letters) and one word (for example, 'javascript' or 'nextjs'), but if my tag is written in Cyrillic and/or two words (for example, 'мощный код' or 'super code'), then no routes are generated correctly.

In my component that displays articles in the list of articles, I can use my own functions like 'transletter' and Lodash:

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import Date from '@/lib/date';
import { transliterate } from '@/lib/transletter';
const _ = require("lodash")

const getTagLink = (tag) => {

    return (
      <Link href={`/blog/tag/${_.kebabCase(transliterate(tag))}`} key={tag}>
       {tag}
      </Link>
    );
  };

export default function Article({ post }) {
    return (
        <article className={`bg-white p-4`}>
            <Link href={`/blog/${post.slug}`}>
                <h3 className='text-2xl mb-2 font-medium hover:text-red-400 cursor-pointer'>
                {post.title}
                </h3>
            </Link>
            <span className='text-gray-600 mb-4 block'>
                <Date dateString={post.date} /> | {post.tags.map(tag => getTagLink(tag)).reduce((prev, curr) => [prev, ', ', curr])}
            </span>
            <p>{post.description}</p>
        </article>
    );
}
```

`${_.kebabCase(transliterate(tag))}` in the link to the tag page does everything right - it transliterates Cyrillic characters for the url and adds a hyphen between the words, that is, instead of `blog/tag/мощный код` turns out `blog/tag/moschnyi-kod`. However, I don't have such a route because [tag].js takes the tag name literally - as it is written.

How do I add something like `_.kebabCase(transliterate(tag))` to my getStaticPath functions or somewhere else so that everything works as it should, so that the desired dynamic route is generated where the tag page will receive a url with the tag name translated into Latin and hyphens between the words

Answer (score 0):

The [dynamic route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) file name `[tag].js` takes whatever [`getStaticPaths`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths) exports. The Link `href` and the path exported from `getStaticPaths` have to match.

So you need to do the same conversion in `getStaticPaths`.

I suggest to create a function like `convertTagToSlug( tag )` and use this same function to create both, the Link `href` and the slug in `getStaticPaths`, e.g.:

```
const convertTagToSlug = function( tag ){
  return _.kebabCase( transliterate( tag ) );
};
```

You probably need both, the original tag and the slug, at several places, so it might be worth building some kind of "library" or "tag registry", so you will have an object or even an auto-generated .js file, like:

```
// tag-registry.js
export const tagRegistry = {
   'tag-1': { slug: 'tag-1', tag: 'tag 1' },
   'tag-2': { slug: 'tag-2', tag: 'tag 2' },
};
```

This way you also have to load and "parse" the data from the file system only once.

Comment: unfortunately I don't understand what needs to be done

Comment: Conceptionally, in `getStaticPaths`, write: `return { params: { _.kebabCase( transliterate( tag ) ) } }`

Comment: if you do so `return {
        paths: [...tags].map((tag) => {
            return {
                params: {
                     _.kebabCase( transliterate( tag ) ) 
                }
            }
        }),
        fallback: false,
    };`  it shows an error

Comment: which error does it show ?

Comment: As if there is not enough comma " , "

Comment: What exactly is the error message ?

Comment: `Expected " , " `   on line   _.kebabCase( transliterate( tag ) )

Comment: Thanks to you, I understood what needs to be done `params: {tag:  _.kebabCase( transliterate( tag ) )}`.  But now I got the opposite effect, because my tags were converted dynamically, now my tags specified in Cyrillic do not correspond to the converted tags

Comment: I understand you need 2 different versions of the tag: The "slug" for the paths, the links and the file names, and the "tag" to be displayed on the page (I'm not sure if you need something else). You will need some kind of "mapping" between the two. I suggest to create a collection of all of them at build time, or use an object like `{ slug: '...', tag: '...' }` _(let's call it "tagSpec")_, and consistently pass that object everywhere (where available) instead of just the `tag` string.

Comment: there must be some simpler method, rather than adding tags to third-party functions.